# How to update a field when another field is set to True using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a visible field on my model, which is a boolean. When that model is updated I want to modify the published_at date field. If it is set to True, I want it to be the current time, if it is set to False, I want it to be None. How can I do that using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Why not simply use that datetime instead of having two and duplicating the logic?

Comment: more flexibility and makes it easier to build an admin dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sqlalchemy event listeners on the mapper you want. E.g.

```
@event.listens_for(MyObj, 'before_insert')
def update_ts_vector(mapper, connection, obj):
    if obj.updated
       obj.last_update = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: should be `before_update` instead of `before_insert`, but the idea works